# Need Help Converting Measurements with XSLT Template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So I've already tried to take this data and make it into a template to convert the cm to inches, it ALSO must be rounded. I have to do it through a template, it can't be done in the main xslt (template='/' it has to be a named template). This is for a class. Here is a small snippet of the data:

```
<org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject
                                serialization="custom">
                                <unserializable-parents/>
                                <map>
                                    <default>
                                        <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
                                        <threshold>12</threshold>
                                    </default>
                                    <int>16</int>
                                    <int>3</int>
                                    <string>uuid</string>
                                    <string>81f182fa-51d0-4790-87c2-912b3e011221</string>
                                    <string>display</string>
                                    <string>Height (cm): 156.0</string>
                                    <string>links</string>
                                    <list>
                                        <org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
                                            <rel>self</rel>
                                            <uri>http://b581.site/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/obs/81f182fa-51d0-4790-87c2-912b3e011221</uri>
                                        </org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
                                    </list>
                                </map>
```

Here is what I've tried thus far:

```
>  <xsl:call-template name="Bologna">
                        <xsl:with-param name= 'rounded' select='substring(./string[4],12,5)'/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
```

I'm probably going to fail if I don't get this. I've had a terrible teacher that is unwilling to teach; if you know of any resources to help me I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <extractor>
            <name>Greg API Bushyeager</name>
        </extractor>
        <query> <method>GET</method>
            <url>
                <address>https://b581.site/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/</address>
                <queryParameters>
                    <parameter key="v" value="full"/>
                    <parameter key="limit" value="500"/>
                    <parameter key="q" value="API"/>
                </queryParameters> </url>
            <headers type="nonHidden">
                <header key="accept" value="application/xml"/>
            </headers>
        </query>
        <xsl:for-each select="//string[(text() = '5090AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')]/../../..">
            <obs uuid="5090AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
                <person>
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select='./org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.SimpleObject[2]/map/string[4]'/>
                </person>
                <originaldatetime>
                    <xsl:value-of  select="./string[8]"/>
                </originaldatetime>

                <height>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cm-to-inch"/>
                    <Units>In</Units>
                </height>
            </obs>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
</xsl:template>
```

How could I call the template you provided, into this template with it only displaying the measurement.  xxin

Idc if the units are there I can always throw em in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess the nature of your assignment, I would think that the purpose is to create a generic template that converts a measurement given in centimeters to inches. Something akin to a function that can be called from any context and does not have a context of its own:

```
<xsl:template name="cm-to-inch">
    <xsl:param name="cm">
    <xsl:value-of select="$cm div 2.54"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which you would then call from another template with the value of a node as the parameter. For example:

**XML**

```
<object>
    <name>box</name>
    <length unit="cm">48</length>
    <width unit="cm">20</width>
    <height unit="cm">36</height>
    <weight unit="kg">1.5</weight>
</object>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@unit='cm']">
    <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:attribute name="unit">in</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:call-template name="cm-to-inch">
            <xsl:with-param name="cm" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="cm-to-inch">
    <xsl:param name="cm"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$cm div 2.54"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<object>
  <name>box</name>
  <length unit="in">18.8976377952756</length>
  <width unit="in">7.874015748031496</width>
  <height unit="in">14.1732283464567</height>
  <weight unit="kg">1.5</weight>
</object>
```

---

> it ALSO must be rounded.

Well, that depends on what *precision* you want it to be rounded to. XSLT's `round()` function rounds to the closest *integer*. If you want greater precision - say 2 decimal places - you need to do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(100 * $cm div 2.54) div 100"/>
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($cm div 2.54, '#.00')"/>
```

but that's not the same thing, because:

1. The result is a *string* that may contain trailing zero/s;
2. Depending on the processor, the rounding rules may be different.

Comment: Thank you sir very much. Your method was much clearer than the alternative. How would I call upon this template within another template to display only the measurement and labeled as height? I haven't seen the method you used above before, I normally use the call-template function; when using this the output displays as Nan. I spent the day looking around and trying to figure out how to call this value into my other template. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: I got it sir! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your sample XML :

```
<map>
<default>
<loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
<threshold>12</threshold>
</default>
<int>16</int>
<int>3</int>
<string>uuid</string>
<string>81f182fa-51d0-4790-87c2-912b3e011221</string>
<string>display</string>
<string>Height (cm): 156.0</string>
<string>links</string>
<list>
<org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
<rel>self</rel>
<uri>http://b581.site/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/obs/81f182fa-51d0-4790-87c2-912b3e011221</uri>
</org.openmrs.module.webservices.rest.web.Hyperlink>
</list>
</map>
```

We can use something like :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="string[contains(.,'Height')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Height (in): ',round(10 * substring-after(.,': ') div 2.54) div 10)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT : ".0 removed", "//" removed.

Output : Height (in): 61.4 | Test : http://xsltransform.net/eiouzmi/6

W3Schools is a nice place to start.

EDIT 2 : Another XPath 1.0 expression to round the converted value (ugly) :

```
concat(floor(substring-after(//string[contains(.,'Height')],': ') div 2.54),'.',substring(substring(substring-after(substring-after(//string[contains(.,'Height')],': ') div 2.54,'.'),1,1)+translate(substring(substring-after(substring-after(//string[contains(.,'Height')],': ') div 2.54,'.'),2,1),'123456789','000001111'),string-length(substring(substring-after(substring-after(//string[contains(.,'Height')],': ') div 2.54,'.'),1,1)+translate(substring(substring-after(substring-after(//string[contains(.,'Height')],': ') div 2.54,'.'),2,1),'123456789','000001111')),1))
```

Output : 61.4

Comment: Unrelated to XSLT, but rounding a measurement to an integer and then appending a decimal zero is something that is not done in science and engineering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision.

Comment: Related to XSLT, taking the value from `//string[contains(.,'Height')]` instead of from the context node will really bomb if there are two or more such strings (not to mention the inefficiency).

Comment: 1. Regarding the rounding, you got a point. Edited. But do we really need that level of precision here ? Just for fun I've added an XPath 1.0 to round correctly the value. 2. Dully noted. Edited. The XML doesn't contain elements with '[@unit='cm']' as you proposed. How is this supposed to work ? You mean to transform the string elements to height elements first ? Just curious.

Comment: **1.** I don't know what level of precision we need here. My issue was not with the level of precision, but with implying a higher level of precision than the one actually computed. **2.** I propose using the context node (as you have now done, while I am writing this). **3.**  I am not sure what that monstrous expression *"to correctly round the converted value"* is supposed to accomplish; I am quite sure there must be a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: For 3, it was just for fun. If you know a better way to round the converted height to 1 decimal with XPath 1.0, feel free to post it. EDIT : `round(10 * height div 2.54) div 10`, works perfectly. Nice ! Thanks for the trick.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you for your advice. I've got one more question, how might I display the measurement and only the measurement within another template with it being labeled Height?

Comment: You mean something like that  ? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDyU/1